# Após fazer insert, redirecionar para a listagem de registros no Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Comecei a trabalhar com o Kohana ontem e me apareceu um problema aqui.

Meu Controller default é o "page" e a action é "home". No Controller "page" tenho essas funcções aqui para se montar o layout:

```
class Controller_Page extends Controller_Index {

 public function action_home(){
     $this->template->title = "Helpdesk";
     $this->template->content = View::factory('home');
 }
 public function action_newClient(){
     $this->template->title = "Helpdesk";
     $this->template->content = View::factory('newClient');
 }
 public function action_listClient(){
     $this->template->title = "Helpdesk";
     $this->template->content = View::factory('listClient');
 }
}
```

Também tenho um Controller chamado "client" e dentro dele essas funções:

```
class Controller_Client extends Controller_Template {
//put your code here
public function action_novo(){
    $cliente = ORM::factory('cliente');        
    $cliente->nomeCliente = $this->request->post('nomeCliente');
    $cliente->cnpjCliente = $this->request->post('cnpjCliente');
    $cliente->dataCadastro = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if($cliente->save()){
        $session = Session::instance();
        $session->set('msg', 'Cliente cadastrado com sucesso!');
        $this->redirect('page');            
    }

}
public function action_lista(){
    $cliente = ORM::factory('cliente')->find_all();
    $view = View::factory('listClient');
    $view->set('clientes',$cliente);
    $this->response->body($view);
}
}
```

No template que está montando, tenho um link que aponta para um formulário, que no caso é a função `action_newClient` do *controller* `page` aonde se cadastra um cliente, funciona normal. Nesse formulário, na action eu estou apontando ela para o método `action_novo` do *controller* `Client`.

Como eu posso redirecionar para uma tela que mostre todos os resultados?

Vejam que fiz o método `action_lista` no *controller* `Client`, mas eu não sei como chamar esse método na *view* que vai listar os dados.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi. Você quer saber como consumir os dados de clientes na view?

Comment: Mais ou menos isso, na verdade eu até consegui fazer o que eu queria e minha dúvida mudou agora
Seria como eu chamo um metodo de um controle externo dentro de outro controller

Comment: Na boa, não faça isso. Não chame um metodo de um controller em outro, isso é uma má prática. O que eu lhe recomendaria é redirecionar para um outro controller, ou extrair o código em comum para sua própria classe.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi vc buscou no banco todos os dados da tabela 'cliente' e ali no

> $view->set('clientes',$cliente);

Agora é sua var na view pra mostrar as infos é a 'clientes' você na verdade não chama o método pois tu ja está na view correspondente.